# Download file to Windows PC from a remote Linux PC where the path to the file contains spaces

Tags: command-line, escaping, sftp, file-transfer, scp

I have tried using both scp and sftp, in both Powershell and at the windows commandline. I also tried doing this from Windows 10 Linux Subsystem but nothing has worked so far.

Part of the problem seems to be escaping the remote Linux file path, which has a space in it. I can't use "\" as this is interpreted incorrectly by Windows. I have also tried using ^ and ` instead and using single and/or double quotes.

Using Windows cmd:

```
C:\Users\psnow>scp dad@192.168.1.4:"//home/naomi/Documents/School Work/Misc/schedule.pdf" c:\Users\psnow\Downloads\schedule.pdf
dad@192.168.1.4's password:
scp: //home/naomi/Documents/School: No such file or directory
scp: Work/Misc/schedule.pdf: No such file or directory
```

This one looked like it got past the space issue, but then came up with this weird error?

```
C:\Users\psnow>scp dad@192.168.1.4:"'//home/naomi/Documents/School Work/Misc/schedule.pdf'" c:\Users\psnow\Downloads\schedule.pdf
dad@192.168.1.4's password:
protocol error: filename does not match request
```

Using Linux Subsystem and Powershell both have similar responses.

All of the tutorials I've found on the subject use simplistic examples without spaces. I'd be happy to use sftp also, but I'm having similar issues with that too.

Comment: And what particular problem did you have with SFTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried escaping without quotes?

```
C:\Users\psnow>scp dad@192.168.1.4://home/naomi/Documents/School\ Work/Misc/schedule.pdf c:\Users\psnow\Downloads\schedule.pdf
```

Or, googling shows me that you have to escape with four backslashes inside ""

```
C:\Users\psnow>scp dad@192.168.1.4:"//home/naomi/Documents/School\\\\ Work/Misc/schedule.pdf" c:\Users\psnow\Downloads\schedule.pdf
```

Unfortunately I cannot try this right now.. hope one of them works for you

Update: Just tried and none of above worked for me

What worked for me:

```
C:\Users\psnow>scp dad@192.168.1.4:"//home/naomi/Documents/'School Work'/Misc/schedule.pdf" c:\Users\psnow\Downloads\schedule.pdf
```

Comment: Excellent! The first two didn't work for me, but the third did. Appreciate your help. I wasted more than an hour on this yesterday and again today, but at least I got there in the end and it saved me from getting up and walking across the room!